# Show Top Results But Limiting Ocurrences by Another Table in SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks, data-warehouse, azure-data-lake

Here's what I have:

- Table with all the sales.
- Table with the vendors.
- Table with the products.

What I need to achieve, is to get a query that would show the top 3 products sold by each vendor along with the amount sold by that vendor for the product and then sort it from top to bottom by the sales made by the vendor in general while showing all the vendors.

So, for example, the vendors are: Mike, Lucas, Amy, Bob, Matt and Agatha and there are 10 products.

The expected output would be:

- Mike -cereal - $400
- Mike -juice -$100
- Mike -soap $50
- Amy -soap $200
- Amy -lettuce $150
- Amy -cheese $100

And so on...

I tried this code but only shows the top selling item for the vendor:

```
SELECT v.vendor_name. p.product_name, sum(f.total) as total
FROM vendors v, sales f, products p
WHERE v.id_vendor = f.vendor and p.id_product = f.product
GROUP BY v.vendor_name, p.product_name
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Some samples of the tables:

[Sales table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpuTC.png)

[Vendor table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDpDV.png)

[Products table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeh73.png)

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08fBJ.png)

[These are the best vendors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FIcf.png)

Like the last image displays, that should be the order in which the vendors appear followed by the column of their 3 top sold products and the amount sold for each one.

So the first vendor would appear 3 times, along with the 3 top sold products and their respective amount.

[Best Vendor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkVBi.png)

Followed by [Second best](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK27t.png).

Comment: can you share samples from input tables, current output and needed output?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. And so on...

Comment: @lemon Just uploaded the info you requested. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

*We tried to reproduce the same scenario and we did it with using `rank and partition by`.*

***Example** :-

Sale Table*

[image]

*Product Table*
[image]

*Vendor table*
[image]

```sql
select ts.vendor_name,  
ts.product_name,  
ts.Total_amount from (  
select tbl_vendor.vendor_name,  
tbl_products.product_name,  
sum(tbl_products.product_amount) 'Total_amount',  
rank() over  
(partition by tbl_vendor.vendor_name order by sum(tbl_products.product_amount) desc) as 'rank'  
from tbl_sale  
inner join tbl_vendor  
on tbl_sale.vendor_id = tbl_vendor.vendor_id  
inner join tbl_products  
on tbl_sale.product_id = tbl_products.product_id  
  
group by tbl_products.product_name,tbl_vendor.vendor_name --order by tbl_vendor.vendor_name,Total_amount desc  
) ts where ts.rank <= 3
```

*Output*

[image]